# PlayStore : App Publish delayed over 3 Week

Tags: android, google-play, delay, publish

I Released app at 02/04
and myApp is still in pending publication

so, I ask to google console,
and they said,
they don't know about that.

i want to know is there are same case like me
or
wait more or do something???

[Still pending publication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj31Y.gif)

Comment: Review app guidance for Family. Do revisit ratings if you are planning to support kids and family.

Comment: i'm not planning to support kids and family>>https://ifh.cc/g/nToNR.png

Comment: Then provide respective info and ratings that will solve the prob.

Comment: here are ratting >> https://ifh.cc/g/tnzJm.png

Comment: https://www.androidcentral.com/google-nukes-all-coronavirus-android-apps-play-store  Hope this could be the reason